# How to move anaconda3 directory?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'd like to move my anaconda3 dir to a different mount.

I forget exactly what it is or how it works beyond it stores some Python packages for me. I forget how I set all this up or how I installed it.

You can see it is mostly lib and pkgs subdirs which fill the space (yellow box, black box shows pie chart and green is anaconda3). It is currently installed on my home dir.

[image]

Comment: https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/configurations/move-directory/

Comment: Quote:`If you simply copy the Anaconda files to a new directory, Anaconda will not work.`. I would suggest you follow the linked advice and uninstall from the old location and reinstall. Consider switiching to miniconda in the process and only install the python packages you really need